# stored procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create procedure p5(age1 IN number) as
     BEGIN
     if age1>18 then 
         insert into t values ( age1 );
     else
         dbms_output.putline('age should be high');
     end if;
end p5;
```

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

I have tried executing  this and i am getting errors listed below

```
SQL> exec p5(20);
BEGIN p5(20); END;
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.P5 is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am still getting these errors

Comment: It seems as if you are running your test pointing to the wrong schema. Are you creating p3 in SYSTEM? Also you close it with `end p2`... is your procedure compiling?

Comment: i have changed p2 to p3 and closed the parenthesis at first line

Comment: Use `show errors` to see details about the "compilation errors"

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems,

```
create or replace procedure p3(age1 IN number) as --you dont need (3) here. Also closing braces are missing.
     BEGIN
     if age1>18 then 
         insert into t values ( age1 );
     else
         dbms_output.put_line('age should be high'); --you were using putline.
     end if;
end p3;  --your proc name is p2 but you are endin p3. Not needed. Just END will also do.
```

I tried running it locally and it is working fine.

```
create table t (age number(3));
```

> Table T created.

```
create procedure p3(age1 IN number) as 
 BEGIN
 if age1>18 then 
     insert into t values ( age1 );
 else
     dbms_output.put_line('age should be high');
 end if;
end p3;
```

> Procedure P3 compiled

```
set serveroutput on;

exec p3(23);
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
exec p3(17);
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> age should be high

```
select * from t;

AGE
23
```

Comment: SQL> create procedure p4(age1 IN number(3)) as
  2       BEGIN
  3       if age1>18 then
  4           insert into t values ( age1 );
  5       else
  6           dbms_output.putline('age should be high');
  7       end if;
  8  end p4;
  9  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> exec p4(20);
BEGIN p4(20); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.P4 is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

i am still getting these erors

Comment: you were using `putline`. Use `put_line`. Updated answer.

Comment: @nagesh please edit your questions **adding** your changes and extra messages you are getting

Comment: @nagesh - YOu didn't read my answer. I told that you dont need `number (3) ` , just use `number`. Then why are you using it again?

Comment: Also if you want to reuse the name, use `create or replace procedure`..

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
dbms_output.put_line
```

instead of

```
dbms_output.putline
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing parenthesis after **p3(age1 IN number(3)**. Try following :

```
create procedure p3(age1 IN number) as
     BEGIN
     if age1>18 then 
         insert into t values ( age1 );
     else
         dbms_output.put_line('age should be high');  -- it should be put_line
     end if;
end p3;  --correct procedure name
```

Comment: @nagesh try now

Comment: Mistake with my tablename. Its working now thank you all